# Cubic extension adjoining a root of an irreducible cubic polynomial.

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, prime-factorization, cubics

Assume $f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is an irreducible cubic polynomial with discriminant $D$, let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ be the three distinct roots of $f(x)=0$. Let $p$ be any odd prime coprime to $D$. Are the following statements equivalent?

(1) $p$ is inert in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$.

(2) $p$ is inert in $\mathbb{Q}(x_1)$.

(3) $p$ is inert in $\mathbb{Q}(x_2)$.

(4) $p$ is inert in $\mathbb{Q}(x_3)$.

Of course, when $D$ is a square, these statements are equivalent. Here "inert" we mean $p$ still remains $p$ when factoring in the cubic extension.

Comment: Those four fields are isomorphic, so the answer is yes.

Comment: What do you mean here by "isomorphic"?

Comment: You know that $\phi(\sum_n a_n x^n)=\sum_n a_n x_1^n$ is an isomorphism $ \Bbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))\to \mathbb{Q}(x_1)$ ?

Comment: @reuns Yes, but $\mathbb{Q}(x_1)$ is a different cubic field with $\mathbb{Q}(x_2)$, when $D$ is not a square.

Comment: But from what I said you have an isomorphism between the two fields and the way it behaves on the ideal $(p)$ of the corresponding ring of integers is obvious.